# How to get unique combinations of pairs in nested tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of pairs of the form [(tuple1), (tuple2)],where the first tuple has variable length and the second has length 1.

Example:

```
[((0, 1, 2), 0), 
((3, 4, 5), 0), 
((12,), 1), 
((0, 1, 4, 7), 1), 
((12,), 1),
((3, 4, 5), 0)]
```

I want `set(pairs)`, where `tuple1_pair_X = tuple1_pair_Y && tuple2_pair_X = tuple2_pair_Y` and not all the possible combinations of tuple1 elements with tuple2.

Desired Output:

```
[((0, 1, 2), 0), 
((3, 4, 5), 0), 
((12,), 1), 
((0, 1, 4, 7), 1)]
```

Comment: Can u provide an implementation which u attempted, which can help us improve your answer

Comment: I only tried the set() command, output is [(0, ), 0, (1, ), 0, (2, ), 0 , ...] and so on for non-duplicate elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep order of your list:

```py
lst = [((0, 1, 2), 0), 
((3, 4, 5), 0), 
((12,), 1), 
((0, 1, 4, 7), 1), 
((12,), 1),
((3, 4, 5), 0)]

sorted(set(lst), key=lst.index)
```

outputs:

```py
[((0, 1, 2), 0), 
((3, 4, 5), 0), 
((12,), 1), 
((0, 1, 4, 7), 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess simply using the set() command on the original list of tuples should work and give your desired output.

```
tup_list = [((0, 1, 2), 0), ((3, 4, 5), 0),((12,), 1),((0, 1, 4, 7), 1),((12,), 1),((3, 4, 5), 0)]
output = list(set(tup_list))
```